# Postdoc interview follow-up: HR or PI and how should I approach the conversation?

Tags: etiquette, postdocs, job-search, interview

I had an interview about 4 days ago for a postdoc in Scandinavia. The interview went well, from what I could tell, and the committee seemed approving and pleased with my answers.  I am thinking of following-up tomorrow, requesting info on the timeframe for a decision. Should I contact the PI or HR rep who was there for the interview as well? Any suggestions on content?

I know they are choosing between 2 candidates so is 5 days too early? I already attached support letters so I'm unsure what happens now in the process. Every day that passes, I get discouraged because this is a project I'd really love to work on.

I would appreciate details regarding the post-interview etiquette and process and usual time-frame in Scandinavia. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

You could contact both, actually, but differently. It is probably early for them to make a decision (scheduling meetings, perhaps), but not to early to follow up with the PI to give thanks for consideration and ask a bit more about the position and the work if you have any remaining question. You can also, safely, express your enthusiasm.

But pressing them for an early decision is probably a mistake.

HR, on the other hand could be asked about the *typical* length of time for decisions. I assume they are not as invested in the decision as the PI.